# trying to get to singleEvents in AppsActivity

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-activity

I am trying to take the [API documentation's](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/apps-activity) example code for AppsActivity.Activities and extend it to singleEvents.  The code snippet below is from the API docs and works as expected

```
function listActivity() {
  var optionalArgs = {
    source: 'drive.google.com',
    'drive.ancestorId': 'root',
    pageSize: 10
  };
  var response = AppsActivity.Activities.list(optionalArgs);
```

When I run the code for the singleEvents, I get the following error: 
TypeError: Cannot find function singleEvents in object AdvancedServiceIdentifier{name=appsactivity, version=v1}. (line 7, file "Code2")

The code snippet (last line) that is causing the error is below:

```
function listActivitySingles() {
  var optionalArgs = {
    source: 'drive.google.com',
    'drive.ancestorId': 'root',
     pageSize: 10
  };
  var response = AppsActivity.activities.singleEvents(optionalArgs);
```

How do I get to the singleEvents?

Thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 0):

How about the following modification? In this modification, `"activities/singleEvents"` was added as `fields`.

```
var optionalArgs = {
  source: 'drive.google.com',
  'drive.ancestorId': 'root',
  pageSize: 10,
  fields: "activities/singleEvents"
};
var response = AppsActivity.Activities.list(optionalArgs);
```

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tanaike. 
I dug around some more and found the code I am looking for..

```
....
do {
    var result = AppsActivity.Activities.list({
      'drive.fileId': fileId,
      'source': 'drive.google.com',
      'pageToken': pageToken
    });
    var activities = result.activities;
    for (var i = 0; i < activities.length; i++) {
      var events = activities[i].singleEvents;
      for (var j = 0; j < events.length; j++) {
         var event = events[j];
         var time = new Date(Number(event.eventTimeMillis));
         var user = event.user;
      ...
```